# Why am I getting a blank slate after the iOS loading screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

My app is displaying the correct iOS loading screen, and then a white screen.

Is it incumbent on me to overwrite the white screen appropriately? Before I added loading screens, I had a background view loaded, and images on top of it. Now it just is plain white.

For displaying the background correctly, does it make sense to have a draw screen method, called from viewDidLoad and from viewDidRotate, and tackle things from there?

I have a ContainerView under a ScrollView, and the ScrollView is provisionally 150x150, which should even if it clips things show non-white pixels inside.

What should I do to get real diagnostics?

Comment: What is the "loading screen"? Are you talking about the static launch images in the app's bundle? Or some other view controller that you're presenting / making root when the app launches?

Comment: can you put screenshots of the transitions your are getting?

Comment: The transition is fine. A screenshot after the transition is at http://jonathanscorner.com/project/screenshot.png - and, by the way, is the "images do not include status bar real estate" rule changed?

Comment: "Loading screen" was a reference to static launch images, not a separate view controller.

Comment: You can debug the code. Start from your application's appdelegate class's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. Make sure there's a view controller that's added as the rootViewController for self.window. If you are not specifying the rootViewController in the code, check there's a "initial view controller" set in the storyboard (its a checkbox for a view controller that should be the starting controller)

Answer (score 0):

> My app is displaying the correct iOS loading screen, and then a white screen.

Something is wrong with your initial view controller, or with the view that it's supposed to load.

> Is it incumbent on me to overwrite the white screen appropriately?

The white screen is probably either your app's window or an empty view. Normally, your app delegate would create a root view controller and load its view into the app's window (possibly automatically if you're using storyboards). It sounds like something happened to adversely affect that process -- your storyboard was changed, your Info.plist (which points the app to the right storyboard or .xib file) was changed, etc.

> For displaying the background correctly, does it make sense to have a
>   draw screen method, called from viewDidLoad and from viewDidRotate,
>   and tackle things from there?

That shouldn't be necessary, at least in the context of your current problem.

> What should I do to get real diagnostics?

Use the debugger. Is the window's root view controller pointing to an instance of the correct class? If yes, does its `view` property point to the correct view? If yes, does the view contain the appropriate objects?